# Trackbar value 1 or 0 issue

Tags: c#

i need my trackbar values to be from 0-1 going through 0.1 0.2... etc returning an Int value

The logics tell me to do it like this:

```
val =  (double)trackBar2.Value / 100.0;
valc = Convert.ToInt32(vol);
```

but the result is either 1 or 0 where 1 is from 50 to 100 and 0 is from 0 to 49

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TrackBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar.aspx) control returns an integer [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.value.aspx) between [`Minimum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.minimum.aspx) and [`Maximum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.maximum.aspx).

If you've set your minimum to 0 and your maximum to 1, then the trackbar will (as you found out) return 0 for the first half of the bar and 1 for the second half.

If you set the minimum to 0 and the maximum to 10, the trackbar will return a value between 0 and 10 for each 1/10th of the bar.

```
int value = trackBar2.Value;
// is between 0 and 10
```

To make this into a floating-point value between 0 and 1, divide by 10.0f:

```
float value = (float)trackBar2.Value / 10.0f;
// is between 0.0 and 1.0
```

You don't want to convert that floating-point value to an integer, as this would simply discard the part after the decimal. So either use the original integer value, or calculate a floating-point value between 0 and 1. Don't use `Convert.ToInt32`.

Answer (score 0):

You just can have it.Integer can not store the decimal values.

Integer type store integers and 0.1 is not an integer.

You can divide by 10 instead of 100 them you will get an int.